# OnItemSelectedListener Spinner Recreate loop - Android

Tags: android, spinner, recreate

I have a spinner and when an item is selected i want to recreate the activity. But when the activity is recreated it keeps constantly recreating because the new itemSelectedListener is triggered. I have fixed the bug but i am interested in why this is happening. Thank you in advance for any insights you offer.

```
    sp_lang.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               recreate();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: First of all, show us you recreate() code. Also, why you want to achieve something like this?

Comment: If you call setSelection() of the Spinner. That will trigger the recreate() everytime.

Comment: i dont use getSelection and i am aware that could happen. I dont have a recreate code. Do i need one i just let android handle it. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the first event with a flag in the OnItemSelectedListener.

```
sp_lang.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        Boolean firstEventConsumed = false;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               if (firstEventConsumed) {
                   recreate();
               } else {
                   firstEventConsumed = true;
               }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

I have found a solution but it is just a workaround. It is not a definitive solution.

It has a strange behaviour when you recreate the activity. When the activity is created for the first time, it doesn't call twice the `onItemSelected`, but when it is recreated it is called twice.

What I have done below is to control when the item is selected by the user (handling the touch event) and when it is done by the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Boolean isUserAction = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // get the spinner
        // create the adapter
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                isUserAction = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (isUserAction) {
                    recreate();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // do nothing
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing more rly. I just use findViewById, then i put data on spinner and add the listener.

Comment: @ChrisPapantonis I have updated my answer. Please, check it out.

Comment: Very elegant. I didnt know why this was happening while testing i figure it out. I used a similar approach too.